# How did the orbits of Phobos and Deimos circularize?

Tags: mars, natural-satellites, phobos, deimos

The satellites of Mars might be captured asteroids. But Phobos has an eccentricity of $0.015$, and Deimos of $3\times10^{-4}$. If they were captured, they likely were captured with rather eccentric orbits. How did their orbits circularize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Astronomers are not still completely sure that these satellites are captured asteroids (see for example [this paper](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2011A%26ARv..19...44R/abstract)). However, in case they are, it's true that their eccentricity should be much higher. There are several theories that provide scenarios for the circularization of the orbits (the most recent I found is [this one](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0019103519305950), which invokes impacts on the moons causing them to start tumbling and exciting the spin), but more data is needed to test these hypothesis (see [this last paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-019-1202-7) for a review of this).